# How can I create a self-referential foreign key on the Django User model?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I'm using the approach of extending the User model by creating a `OnetoOne` relationship between `User` and a `UserProfile` class. This means that I can't directly add fields to the `User` model. How then can I create a foreign key on the `User` model to itself?

Comment: do you want a foreign key from `User` to `User` itself?

Comment: why not create it from `UserProfile` to `UserProfile` ?

Comment: I've been using `User` for the for the foreign key of all other models that have a relationship with with users in some way so that I'm always performing queries with the `User` query manager rather than the `UserProfile` query manager (which I feel makes more sense semantically). Maybe this is one time I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

you can do something like `models.ForeignKey('self')`